# jQuery validate with only a single click

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

jQuery Validation is working fine, but when I add the following code to prevent clicking the submit button twice, it stops validating. Why? And how do I get around it?

```
var form = $("form.single-click");
if (form.length > 0 && form.validate) {
    form.validate({
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            $("form [type=submit]").prop("disabled", true);
            form.submit();
        }
    });
}
```

The line that disables the submit button has no effect on whether validation occurs, but is included as that is my intent.

UPDATE: I am using this within ASP.NET MVC 4 so there is a library that already calls validate. The above method manages to intercept it, but then, of course, there is no validation.

Comment: Are you saying there is other code somewhere that also calls `.validate()` for the same form(s)?

Comment: The `validate()` code above is mine. I added it to a separate JS file that is loaded last to avoid an accidental double click.

Comment: So (again) is there another call to `.validate()` somewhere? You say "jQuery Validation is working fine..." - what does the code look like when it works?

Comment: `.validate()` is not the testing method.  It _is_ the method used to _initialize_ the plugin on the form and it gets called only once.  Keep this in mind when constructing your logic.

Comment: Ah yes! I am using ASP.NET MVC 4, so it has it's own `validate()` in a library.